# Проверка вхождения в tuple()

Tags: python

Каким способом можно проверить входит ли координата point_A (x, y) в tuple().
При сравнении двух разных типов выводит ошибку. Нужно вывести True or False

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

```
point_1 = (23, 34)

# Если точка point лежит внутри того самого круга [центр в начале координат (0, 0), radius = 42],
# то выведите на консоль True, Или False, если точка лежит вовне круга.

distance = ((point_1[0] ** 2 + point_1[1] **2) * .5)
print('Расcтояние между началом координат и точкой "point_1":', distance)
```

Comment: а про тип point_A надо экстрасенсорно догодатся?

Comment: Значит надо правильно сравнивать 

Comment: В какой из этих трех строк возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде нет синтаксической ошибки, только семантическая — потому что вы в конце вместо возведения в степень (оператор `**`) применили умножение (оператор `*`).

Когда, с другой страны, вы хотите тест, если число является первой или второй координатой заданной пары, например если число `x` есть первой координатой пары `point`, один подход может быть таким:

```
point_x, point_y = point    # point может быть например (2, 5)
x == point_x                # True или False
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
isInner = lambda p, r : (p[0]**2 + p[1]**2) ** .5 <= r

point = (23, 34)
radius = 42

print(isInner(point, radius))
```

Результат:

```py
True
```